# How to store images and keys to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: nsstring, uiimage, nsmutabledictionary

I'm receiving an error when writing to my NSMutableDictionary "dictionary".

**When implementing (below) from my item list class:**

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)i forKey:(NSString *)s
{
[dictionary setObject:i forKey:s];
// Create full path for image
NSString *imagePath = [self imagePathForKey:s];

// Turn image into JPEG data,
NSData *d = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(i, 0.5);

// Write it to full path
[d writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
```

**From DetailViewController:imagePickerController:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *oldKey = [_detailItem imageKey];

//did the item already have an image
if (oldKey) {
    //delete old image
    [[RoomList sharedStore] deleteImageForKey:oldKey];
}

//get picked image from info dictionary
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

//create CFUUID object; it knows how to create uique identifier strings
CFUUIDRef newUniqueID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

//create string from unique identifier
CFStringRef newUniqueIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);

//use unique ID to set our item's imageKey
NSString *key = (__bridge NSString *)newUniqueIDString;
[_detailItem setImageKey:key];
NSLog(@"image key: %@", key);

[_detailItem setImage:image forKey:key];

//tell objects ointed to by newUniqueIDString and newUniqueID to lose an owner to avoid
//memory leak
CFRelease(newUniqueIDString);
CFRelease(newUniqueID);

//remove image picker (dismiss method)
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self configureView];
}
```

**I am being met with the following error, that is tied to the [_detailItem setImage:image forKey:key]; operation in imagePickerController:** -[NSManagedObject setImage:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8195770

My guess is that either the UIImage *image, NSString *key, or both are not able to be passed to the objectForKey method "setImage:forKey".  Any way of fixing this, or getting around it?

Thanks!

Comment: _detailItem is an NSManagedObject and it does not recognize the setImage forKey selector. You will have to verify this in order to make sure you set the correct selector, possibly setValue:forKey: if you have the managed object underlying set to NSData or id in CoreData

Comment: 100% correct, thanks!  "setImage:forKey" was not part of the NSManagedObject.  Changed it to the proper attribute and all is well.